# How to save server response's token to User Defaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

```
     response {
        data = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJmaGZnZkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1NjkyNTAxMzQsImlhdCI6MTU2OTIzMjEzNH0.1Au13IjR89AvxowniN42ngaDuQgupWRgJQvSq00JbO73HuKyFbjB3u4XtjOSID1-Ht1A4vDQlmsMtn70rFJzJg";
        localDateTime = "2019-09-23T15:18:54.182";
        message = "Employee registration sucessfull";
        response = 1;
}
```

I got this response from the server when I register .

Can someone please help me how to save this token in locally using `NSUserDefaults`.

I need to use this token in other class

Comment: can you please show what u have done to save this

Comment: NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
    [userDefaults setObject:@"data"
                     forKey:@"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzdHJpbmciLCJleHAiOjE1NjkyNDkwNTYsImlhdCI6MTU2OTIzMTA1Nn0.FVIlt12HdtAUev6a8V1h4ulS-brn2-IlRwoUYBrlGD5twoe6h5g6BSIRLxn6dCCLY0PZA6m6qpqJe0Hodkgb6Q"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"data"];    m using same class

Comment: m trying as hardcode firstly

Comment: NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; [userDefaults setObject:@"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzdHJpbmciLCJleHAiOjE1NjkyNDkwNTYsImlhdCI6MTU2OTIzMTA1Nn0.FVIlt12HdtAUev6a8V1h4ulS-brn2-IlRwoUYBrlGD5twoe6h5g6BSIRLxn6dCCLY0PZA6m6qpqJe0Hodkgb6Q" forKey:@"data"]; [userDefaults synchronize]; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"data"] .  try this way

Comment: What is `response` and where does it come from?

Comment: when register employee screen then when click registration button I got response with token

Comment: response {
        data = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJmaGZnZkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1NjkyNTAxMzQsImlhdCI6MTU2OTIzMjEzNH0.1Au13IjR89AvxowniN42ngaDuQgupWRgJQvSq00JbO73HuKyFbjB3u4XtjOSID1-Ht1A4vDQlmsMtn70rFJzJg";
        localDateTime = "2019-09-23T15:18:54.182";
        message = "Employee registration sucessfull";
        response = 1;
}

Comment: where we store this token-----NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; [userDefaults setObject:@"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzdHJpbmciLCJleHAiOjE1NjkyNDkwNTYsImlhdCI6MTU2OTIzMTA1Nn0.FVIlt12HdtAUev6a8V1h4ulS-brn2-IlRwoUYBrlGD5twoe6h5g6BSIRLxn6dCCLY0PZA6m6qpqJe0Hodkgb6Q" forKey:@"data"]; [userDefaults synchronize]; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"data"]   same view controller or another nsobject class

Comment: You shouldn't be storing authentication tokens in UserDefaults, better to store them in Keychain, which is more secure and you will have availability guarantee. You can use some wrapper to make it easier, like [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess)